# With the command pv it is possible to clone a drive, how do I mount it?

Tags: mount, disk-image, pv

I was able to backup a drive using the following command.

```
pv -EE /dev/sda > disk-image.img
```

This is all well and good, but now I have no way of seeing the files unless I use this command

```
pv disk-image.img > /dev/sda
```

This, of course, writes the data back to the disk which is not what I want to do. My question is what can I do to mount the `.img` file itself instead of just writing back to a disk?

---

I've tried mounting using loop but it seems to complain about an invalid NTFS.

```
$ mount -o loop disk-image.img
mount: disk-image.img: can't find in /etc/fstab.
$ mount -o loop disk-image.img /mnt/disk-image/
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/loop32': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/loop32' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

Comment: What does `file disk-image.img` tell you?

Comment: disk-image.img: DOS/MBR boot sector

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You backed up the whole disk including the MBR (512 bytes), and not a *simple* partition which you can mount, so you have to skip the MBR.

Please try with:

```
sudo losetup -o 512 /dev/loop0 disk-image.img
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/loop0 /mnt
```

**Edit:** as suggested by @grawity:

```
sudo losetup --partscan /dev/loop0 disk-image.img
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/loop0 /mnt
```

Comment: Splendid insight!

Comment: Why aren't you using `losetup --partscan`? How do you know that the NTFS partition will start at the 1st sector right after the MBR? Most disks have it start at sector 63 or even 2048.

Comment: There's also the possibility of multiple partitions existing. You should use `kpartx` instead (which will internally handle `losetup` for each relevant partition).

Comment: @grawity May be an alternative solution!

Comment: @Bob Please post an answer that can be voted on.

Answer (score 2):

As others have already pointed out,

```
sudo losetup /dev/loop0 /path/to/disk-image.img
```

will set up a virtual block device that can be used to access the file, but it does not give you easy access to the partitions.

However, there is another command you can use after that to gain access to all the partitions within the disk image file, without manually calculating partition offsets:

```
sudo kpartx -a /dev/loop0
```

This will read the partition table within the disk image, and will create devices like `/dev/mapper/loop0p1`, `/dev/mapper/loop0p2` etc. for all the partitions. You can use those to mount the partitions normally.

(If you don't remember what each partition is, you could use `fdisk -l /dev/loop0` to view the partition table within the disk image; just note that many versions of `fdisk` will display the names of the partition devices a little oddly in this situation.)

Once you've done accessing the disk image, you can undo this set-up by unmounting the partitions you've mounted, and then using two commands:

```
sudo kpartx -d /dev/loop0   # remove the /dev/mapper/loop0pN partition mappings
sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0  # disconnect the image file from the loop device
```

The `kpartx` command was originally developed as a tool for multipathed devices (as used with SAN storage systems), but it is perfectly usable with disk images too.

Answer (score 0):

Install [p7zip-full](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/p7zip) if you don't have it already, then take a look with

```
sudo 7z  /pathtowhereitis/whatever.img
```

Comment: Where is this image mounted?

Comment: @pipe, please consider placing this question up top, to the original poster tisaconundrum, as a comment to the original post. They may not see it down here.

Comment: No, I'm asking _you_, who wrote this answer. Using the command that you have presented as the solution to the problem of mounting the image, where can I then access the files?

Comment: Current directory